# Two Tables With Effective Dates In Which Data Can Vary Independently

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am developing a database in MS Access 2010.  I have two tables, one for Deals (tblDeals), and one for the Deal Items (tblDealItems).

I need to track the history for the data in these tables, so I am using a DateEffective field  and DateEnd field in each of them.

The problem is that the data in each of the two tables can vary independently on different dates, which makes it difficult (impossible for me, actually) to return a recordset which has the true history of the series of events which occur during the deal.

The tables have the following data for one particular deal, "Deal 3":

```
tblDeals:
DealID DealName AssetClassID DateEffective DateEnd
------ -------- ------------ ------------- -------
3      Deal 3   3            1 Jan 2010    1 Jul 2011
3      Deal 3   2            1 Jul 2011    1 Oct 2011
3      Deal 3   1            1 Oct 2011 

tblDealItems:
DealItemID DealID CategoryID ParticipantID Amount DateEffective DateEnd
---------- ------ ---------- ------------- ------ ------------- -------
13         3      3          2             1500   1 Jan 2010    1 Jun 2011
13         3      1          2             1500   1 Jun 2011    6 Jun 2011
13         3      1          2             6000   6 Jun 2011    1 Sep 2011
13         3      3          2             6000   1 Sep 2011
```

So the actual history of the Deal is this (created manually - this (with the exception of the "Description" column - which is there so it is obvious what has changed in each row) is what I would like to return):

```
Date       (Description)         DealID DealName AssetClassID CategoryID ParticipantID Amount
---------- --------------------- ------ -------- ------------ ---------- ------------- ------
1 Jan 2010 (Deal 3 Created)      3      Deal 3   3            3          2             1500
1 Jun 2011 (Category Changed)    3      Deal 3   3            1          2             1500
6 Jun 2011 (Amount Changed)      3      Deal 3   3            1          2             6000
1 Jul 2011 (Asset Class Changed) 3      Deal 3   2            1          2             6000
1 Sep 2011 (Category Changed)    3      Deal 3   2            3          2             6000
1 Oct 2011 (Asset Class Changed) 3      Deal 3   1            3          2             6000
```

Obviously, if I join the two tables on their shared key, I get a table with twelve rows (3 * 4) instead of the six rows which describe the history.

I know that I need to be able to join the tables together in some way so that I can generate the true history of the deal, but I just don't know how! (I'm really an Excel guy, not a SQL one!)

I think I have worked out exactly what is required to solve the problem specified above:

For each date in qryDates, I need to find the largest tblDeals.DateEffective which is less than or equal to that date and the largest tblDealItems.DateEffective which is less than or equal to that date.

I the need to return the row from a query joining tblDeals and tblDealItems which has those two exact dates.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: you'll never get the DESCRIPTION, as you need to compare valued in different rows. The other clolumns are easy to get with the CASE WHEN and a WHERE comparing start and end dates in the 12 rows of the join.

Comment: Hi Martin:  Yes, I agree.  The DESCRIPTION is an attribute I've added so that it is obvious to a human what the change is in each row.  I will amend the question to account for this.

Comment: Hi Martin: It is fine to know that this is easy for you, but it is not helpful to tell me that it is easy for you!  I am unable to understand what is required to achieve this result, hence my asking the question.  If it is easy, I would be grateful if you could assist me a bit further in answering this.

Comment: It is not easy for anyone to use CASE WHEN with Access (Jet/ACE) database engine ... because they don't support it.  :-)

Comment: [Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)

Comment: @HansUp -- arguably `SWITCH()` is Access's support for Standard SQL's `CASE`, as you are aware (and I note the smiley).

Comment: @onedaywhen -- Thank you for the link, it is certainly an interesting article, but I am struggling to understand how it helps me solve my conundrum.  I need to be able to write some SQL which returns the most recent results into a query where the date is not available.  This is because events could occur independently in either table, which means that a simple join is not enough.  I am sure the answer is a sub query and I am struggling with it presently.

Comment: I erroneously concluded that your "After some thought" was an update to your original question, indicating you'd found a solution, hence I wondered if using a calendar table would help simplify a solution you already have. But it seems you haven't found a solution yet. I admit to only skim reading this question, it seems quite complex. I'll try to take a deeper look later.

Comment: @onedaywhen Thank you.  I will edit the "after some thought", which does imply a solution.  Rest assured it's still horrible for me!

Comment: I'm not sure how `tblReportingDates` fits in. Can you post relevant data for this table too?

Comment: Now I have to admit to being really stupid. I am working on two different (but similar databases). One of them (the other one) has tblReportingDate, which is a table of all the valid reporting dates. THIS database on the other hand just records the date that data changed, so there is no tblReportingDate. I've removed it from the question above. I was able to solve the similar problem when there was the table of reporting dates but I am still stuck on this one. Many thanks for any help you are able to offer.

Comment: Also `RoleID` has seemingly appeared from nowhere ;)

Comment: In my sample data Role ID didn't change, so I thought to leave it out.  I'm removing it from the Sample output table now, but it is a field in tblDealItems

Comment: Just trying get it as simple as possible so that there are no extraneous elements confusing the situation.  @onedaywhere is being a good editor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm omitting 'Description' for the moment because it adds quite a bit of complexity (and might be better suited to a report anyhow):

First

```
 CREATE VIEW qryDates 
 AS
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.DealID, 
         T1.DateEffective AS tblDeals_DateEffective, 
         (
          SELECT MAX(T2.DateEffective)
            FROM tblDealItems AS T2
           WHERE T1.DealID = T2.DealID
                 AND T2.DateEffective <= T1.DateEffective
         ) AS tblDealItems_DateEffective
    FROM tblDeals AS T1;
```

Second:

```
 CREATE VIEW qryDates2
 AS
  SELECT DISTINCT T2.DealID, 
         T2.DateEffective AS tblDealItems_DateEffective, 
         (
          SELECT MAX(T1.DateEffective)
            FROM tblDeals AS T1
           WHERE T1.DealID = T2.DealID
                 AND T1.DateEffective <= T2.DateEffective
         ) AS tblDeals_DateEffective
    FROM tblDealItems AS T2
```

Then

```
SELECT T2.DateEffective AS [Date], '' AS Description, 
       T1.DealName, T1.AssetClassID, 
       T2.CategoryID, T2.ParticipantID, T2.Amount
  FROM (
       tblDeals AS T1
       INNER JOIN 
       qryDates2 AS Q2
          ON T1.DateEffective = Q2.tblDeals_DateEffective
             AND T1.DealID = Q2.DealID
       )
       INNER JOIN tblDealItems AS T2
          ON T2.DateEffective = Q2.tblDealItems_DateEffective
             AND T2.DealID = Q2.DealID
UNION 
SELECT T1.DateEffective AS [Date], '' AS Description, 
       T1.DealName, T1.AssetClassID, 
       T2.CategoryID, T2.ParticipantID, T2.Amount
  FROM (
       tblDeals AS T1
       INNER JOIN 
       qryDates AS Q1 
          ON T1.DateEffective = Q1.tblDeals_DateEffective
             AND T1.DealID = Q1.DealID
       )
       INNER JOIN tblDealItems AS T2
          ON T2.DateEffective = Q1.tblDealItems_DateEffective
             AND T2.DealID = Q1.DealID;
```

The quality of the data in your sample is good: in reality the joins may need to be outer to compensate for bad data. Note your `tblDeals` table is not fully normlized (hint: `DealName` is repeated).

Note:

> Obviously, if I join the two tables on their shared key, I get a table
>   with twelve rows (3 * 4) instead of the six rows which describe the
>   history.

you can get the set of unique event dates for each deal using `UNION`:

```
SELECT DealID, DateEffective
  FROM tblDeals
UNION 
SELECT DealID, DateEffective
  FROM tblDealItems;
```

---

Here's a repro: creates a new mdb in temp folder, creates tables and views (note `CREATE VIEW` does work in Access ;) , adds test data (as per question) then executes query and shows results in a messagebox; no references required, just copy+paste into any VBA module e.g. use a new Excel workbook :)

```
Sub NickNick2()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"

    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String

      Sql = "CREATE TABLE tblDeals (DealID INT, DealName VARCHAR(100), AssetClassID INT, DateEffective DATETIME, DateEnd DATETIME);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = "CREATE TABLE tblDealItems (DealItemID INT, DealID INT, CategoryID INT, ParticipantID INT, Amount INT, DateEffective DATETIME, DateEnd DATETIME);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
          " CREATE VIEW qryDates  " & _
          " AS " & _
          "  SELECT DISTINCT T1.DealID,  " & _
          "         T1.DateEffective AS tblDeals_DateEffective,  " & _
          "         ( " & _
          "          SELECT MAX(T2.DateEffective) " & _
          "            FROM tblDealItems AS T2 " & _
          "           WHERE T1.DealID = T2.DealID " & _
          "                 AND T2.DateEffective <= T1.DateEffective " & _
          "         ) AS tblDealItems_DateEffective " & _
          "    FROM tblDeals AS T1;"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      " CREATE VIEW qryDates2 " & _
      " AS " & _
      "  SELECT DISTINCT T2.DealID,  " & _
      "         T2.DateEffective AS tblDealItems_DateEffective,  " & _
      "         ( " & _
      "          SELECT MAX(T1.DateEffective) " & _
      "            FROM tblDeals AS T1 " & _
      "           WHERE T1.DealID = T2.DealID " & _
      "                 AND T1.DateEffective <= T2.DateEffective " & _
      "         ) AS tblDeals_DateEffective " & _
      "    FROM tblDealItems AS T2;"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDeals VALUES (3, 'Deal 3', 3, '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-07-01 00:00:00');"
      .Execute Sql
      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDeals VALUES (3, 'Deal 3', 2, '2011-07-01 00:00:00', '2011-10-01 00:00:00');"
      .Execute Sql
      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDeals VALUES (3, 'Deal 3', 1, '2011-10-01 00:00:00', NULL);"
      .Execute Sql
      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDealItems VALUES (13, 3, 3, 2, 1500, '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-06-01 00:00:00');"
      .Execute Sql
      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDealItems VALUES (13, 3, 1, 2, 1500, '2011-06-01 00:00:00', '2011-06-06 00:00:00');"
      .Execute Sql
      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDealItems VALUES (13, 3, 1, 2, 6000, '2011-06-06 00:00:00', '2011-09-01 00:00:00');"
      .Execute Sql
      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO tblDealItems VALUES (13, 3, 3, 2, 6000, '2011-09-01 00:00:00', NULL);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "SELECT T2.DateEffective AS [Date], '' AS Description, " & _
      "       T1.DealName, T1.AssetClassID,  " & _
      "       T2.CategoryID, T2.ParticipantID, T2.Amount " & _
      "  FROM ( " & _
      "       tblDeals AS T1 " & _
      "       INNER JOIN  " & _
      "       qryDates2 AS Q2 " & _
      "          ON T1.DateEffective = Q2.tblDeals_DateEffective " & _
      "             AND T1.DealID = Q2.DealID " & _
      "       ) " & _
      "       INNER JOIN tblDealItems AS T2 " & _
      "          ON T2.DateEffective = Q2.tblDealItems_DateEffective " & _
      "             AND T2.DealID = Q2.DealID " & _
      "UNION  " & _
      "SELECT T1.DateEffective AS [Date], '' AS Description,  " & _
      "       T1.DealName, T1.AssetClassID,  " & _
      "       T2.CategoryID, T2.ParticipantID, T2.Amount " & _
      "  FROM ( " & _
      "       tblDeals AS T1 " & _
      "       INNER JOIN  " & _
      "       qryDates AS Q1  " & _
      "          ON T1.DateEffective = Q1.tblDeals_DateEffective " & _
      "             AND T1.DealID = Q1.DealID " & _
      "       ) "
      Sql = Sql & _
      "       INNER JOIN tblDealItems AS T2 " & _
      "          ON T2.DateEffective = Q1.tblDealItems_DateEffective " & _
      "             AND T2.DealID = Q1.DealID " & _
      " ORDER " & _
      "    BY 1;"

      Dim rs
      Set rs = .Execute(Sql)
      MsgBox rs.GetString

    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the information on the Union of the DateEffectives, this was where I can give myself a small pat on the back in that I was able to discover that myself, although it does not play a part in the ultimate solution.

Comment: @Nick: hope you can follow the above to getting the `Description` column. And don't forget to accept the best answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the denormalisation.  Because the table records the DateEffective and DateEnd, every time there is a UPDATE change to the data, instead of the data being overwritten, the DateEnd field is updated and a new row with all the previous values (and the changed one(s) are then added at the end of the database.  I understand that this is necessarily involve some denormalisation.  Do you have a better suggestion for tracking the history of the records?

Comment: Arrrgh! It doesn't work!  I have five dummy deals in my test DB, and the query is returning all the permuations for each of the different deals.  Should there be another join somehwere so it's not just dates that are being checked, but also the ID to ensure that they are the correct combo.  Also (and rather belatedly, this may alternatively be the source of the problem) does not DateEnd need to be taken into account so that old items are only being matched with items that are not newer...  Blimey this is a terrifically difficult problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even when I have removed all the other Deals from both tables, the query now return 14(!) records. :(

Comment: "Should there be another join somehwere so it's not just dates that are being checked, but also the ID" -- yes, my bad! Now corrected.

Comment: Sorry to be an annoying Gimboid.  It now says "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''."  I've run it through the SQL parser at http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm (which is normally pretty good at picking up SQL errors) and it seems OK.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate the help!  This is the most difficult thing I've done in a while :)

Comment: On the `CREATE VIEW` or the query?

Comment: The query.  It's MS Access, so no views, I'm afraid, just queries.  That creates and runs with no problem.  The first part of the Union also runs with no problem.  The second part of the Union does not want to run at all, errors with the noted message.

Comment: Access does indeed support [`CREATE VIEW`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-view-statement-HP001032223.aspx) when in [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx).

Comment: The query works for me... but then I'm using SQL Server :) I'll try converting to Access...

Comment: When I take off the join to T2, I can open it in the QBE grid, and then add T2 back in and recreate the joins, and that works after a fashion but when I go to SQL view, the joins are in a different order and they have parentheses around them.  When I then add in the first part of the Union, I am back to having 14 records returned instead of the six expected.

Comment: "but then I'm using SQL Server" Lucky you!

Comment: Thanks for the hint about parens: I've edited to make the syntax Access-friendly :)

Comment: Getting closer.  Now it works, but it still returns 14 rows (instead of the six which are required).

Comment: Hi onedaywin, thank you very much for that VBA. Your sample database is different from mine in that in your sample, there was no change in AssetClassID in tblDeal.  When that condition holds, your query returns all six records.  However, if you have changes in AssetClassID (as in my original data) you will find that the query does not return the correct results.  Please amend your data to show AssetClassID changing to 2 on 1 July 2011 and to 3 on 1 Oct 2011, then rerun your query.  I am sure it will return 14 rows.

Comment: Yes, I did get the data wrong, my apologies :) Now fixed by adding a second view which essentially switches the tables of the first. Seems to work but now *appears* that you may be able to eliminate the `UNION` and do it in one query -- I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: U DA MAN!  Mucho gracias amigo!  Wow, you have no idea how long I sweated over that.  I'll examine what you've don in great detail to suck every last portion of knowledge out of it that I can.  Have a super afternoon!  Thanks!

Comment: @Nick: Got there in the end ;) p.s. I came from an Excel background too but got sucked into the SQL world, so watch out!